# How to Upload PDF to data under window forms using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Project Fund Request Form Image:

[image]

So I am creating a banking application as part of my end of semester project called ICube, the banking aspect of the applications allows an employee of the organization to view their salaries as well as request personal loans as well as request for funds for a new project.

I have been able to code the entire banking application using LINQ on windows forms in C# even though I am new to programming but I am facing a little challenge attempting to upload PDF and Word documents as part of the request for the fund for the project request form. user is required to upload a budget in PDF for word as part of the request.

Can someone kindly help me with a simple code to upload PDF and Word document to the database using LINQ under WinForms in c#?

Answer (score 0):

To store files to a database, you have to convert those files to a type that the database understands. For example you can convert the pdf file to a string.

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("pathOfPdfFile");
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Then, when you want to retrieve it, you can use

```
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str);
File.WriteAllBytes("pathToSaveTheFile", bytes);
```

Comment: please can you explain this part to me ("path");     is it the file path?

Comment: am new to this, even though i understand your code i do not know how to apply it

Comment: Yes it is the file path. Once you convert the pdf file to a string, you can then store this string to your database as you would with any other string. Keep in mind it will be a pretty long string

Comment: You have not provided any example of how your code works, the database type, the way you get the document from the user etc, so I cannot give you a more specific answer.